# how are these columns changing their configuration without javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking around for a way to arrange content differently depending on screen size when I noticed [this site](http://jordanyoung.com/). Quite a nice looking site too. As I change my browser's size, the column configuration changes? When I reduce to the very minimum size or visit it on a phone, the large image on top disappears completely, leaving only the small icons. I've turned off javascript, and this still happens. Also, it works in my ie8, so I'm guessing it's not an HTML5 thang. How is it being done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This effect is not being done by Javascript, instead it is being done by [CSS @media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). [Chris Coyier of CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) has a great intro to @media queries

Simply, it allows you to specify the scope of a stylesheet based on some boolean expression (such as checking if the window width is a specific width used in that example you saw) and then apply specific styles thus making it responsive design

Comment: Ah! there you go. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any advantage to "faking it with javascript" for IE8 and below as the article suggests, and not using the javascript for more modern browsers. I mean, if you're going to do that anyway, why use media queries _and_ javascript? I feel I'm missing something..

Comment: Why ask everyone to download and run the JS file if only a couple browsers actually need it?  Native is almost always better if it is available.

Comment: @cimmanon yeah, i suppose I would agree with that in practice, but it does seem like it would be about 30 lines of javascript at the very most. Do you really get that much of a performance boost?